# Write file on Android with Onedrive and StorageAccessFramework

Tags: android, onedrive, saf

I use Storage Access Framework (SAF) on Android with OneDrive. Reading a file works fine, but when i try to save file, it doesn't work (i get a "Bad File Number" issue)

Using SAF with GoogleDrive in the same way works perfectly.

Is this because OneDrive implementation of SAF doesn't support writing files, or something like that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It sounds like the OneDrive SAF implementation might be returning an improper values.  If you could reach out to me with a more specific details/example about what is wrong can investigate the experience.

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive for Android only supports read operations via the Storage Access Framework in Android.

If you would like to save files to OneDrive, there is a picker & saver interface avaliable that is avaliable.  See [OneDrive-Picker-Android](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-picker-android) on github for more information.

Comment: Thanks... Any chance it will work in the future? The point of SAF is to avoid implementing the api picker of each cloud providers... We need to be able to write file with it.